# How do I forward output from X to multiple clients?

Tags: process, x11

I am currently building a server using Debian Squeeze. It will be administered by myself and a friend, and I am wondering if it is possible to forward the output from ONE process to TWO clients.

As an example, process abc is running on the server. It uses X for graphical output. I would like to be able to view and control its X window on both client computers at the same time. This way, both my friend and I would be able to see the status of process abc and send commands to it from our remote computers. The only solutions that I have found so far indicate that the process can only connect to one X instance at a time, requiring that for me to see the X output, my friend would have to disconnect. Is there a way for both of us to connect and control the same process at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that X forwarding allows only one connection. However, you can try VNC to achieve your desired setup.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe able to use VNC to control the remote desktop (the ([Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X11vnc)) states that you maybe able to set x11vnc to forward the root desktop, which you both may be able to access at the same time; I haven't tried it so I can't say for certain).